# Is jQuery UI a jQuery Plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, plugins

Is jQuery UI considered a jQuery Plugin?

Is it possible to use jQuery UI without jQuery?

Comment: Both of these questions are answered on the jQuery UI homepage (http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a specific programming question.

Comment: This question was written 5 years ago.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is jQuery UI considered a jQuery Plugin?

It is not a single plugin but a collection of plugins and UI widgets.

> Is it possible to use jQuery UI without jQuery?

No, jQuery UI is built on top of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it more of an extension to jQuery. It does use the core jQuery Library, which makes sense otherwise there would be 2 versions.

more info here: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Getting_Started

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI is an official jQuery project which provides UI plugins, widgets, effects, interactions and theming.

Answer (score 0):

It is a series of plugins, and you don't have to add the whole thing if you dont want. You can [download just what you need](http://jqueryui.com/download) to save some page weight.

note: you do need the core to do anything